# Azure Devops - Build Automation

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, continuous-build

I have a Azure DevOps Git Repo with many solutions in it, and are starting down the path of build, test, deploy automation.

I figured out how to run a rebuild if any file changes in the repo.

However, since the repo has many solutions in it, I only want to run a given rebuild of a solution if a specific subfolder changes.

Is that possible, and if so, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you start by reading the documentation on the build system? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, daniel, i did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use path based trigger filters (i'm fairly certain they are only supported in yaml builds). example:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - folder1/*
      - folder2/somefile
      - etc
```

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2